# Eloquent: How to get the inverse

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables namely:

1. People (with columns: id & name)
2. Assignments (with columns: person_id & project_id)
3. Projects (with columns: id & title)

I have the Assignments table because each person can be assigned to many projects.

I have these three models:

```
// People.php 
public function projectAssigned()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assignment', 'person_id');
} 

// Assignment.php
public function person()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\People', 'person_id');
}  

public function project()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
}

public function task()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'assignment_id');
} 

// Project.php
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assignment', 'project_id');
}
```

Getting the list of people assigned in a specific project is easy:

```
how I get it:
@foreach($project->assignment as $person)
<tr>
<td>{{$person->person->firstname.' '.$person->person->lastname}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

My Question is: How do I get the list of people **NOT ASSIGNED** in a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

For example in your `Person` Model add method:

```
public function getNotInProject($projectId) {
    return $this
        ->leftJoin('assignment', 'assignment.person_id', '=', 'person.id')
        ->where('assignment.project_id', '<>', $projectId)
        ->get();
}
```

and then You'll get collection of persons:

```
@foreach(Person::getNotInProject($project->id) as $person)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$person->firstname.' '.$person->lastname}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```